# Sending data through coded button/function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a button I created for a tableViewCell footer, and want to pass the section when the button is pressed, but when I print out the section, it is a completely arbitrary number, how can I pass the section Int when the button is pressed?

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            
            
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle("Add Set", for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CurrentSessionVC.addSetPressed(section:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            return button
        }


    @objc func addSetPressed(section: Int){
            //prints 4349567072
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tag` property (that is available in any `UIView` object) and the fact that `addTarget(_:action:for:)`, which is available to all `UIControl` objects, passes the sender (here your button instance) to the selector:

```
//...
let button = UIButton()
button.tag = section // or any other int
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
//...

@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let section = sender.tag
}
```

You can read more about the Target-Action Mechanism [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol#1943645)